# Simulink: Synchronizing and timing

Tags: matlab, synchronization, simulink

in order to simulate some processes I have a problem with getting a predefined working order of my self modeled blocks.

How can I be sure, that for example Block A must be finished before Block B and C start working?

The problem is, that some Blocks shall work after some others and some shall not. I must admit I have not much experience with Simulink in order of doing time-depending things (althought basic knowledge of simulink is available).

For instance this scenario shall be realised:

```
A -> B, C -> D, E, F
```

The main thing is, that all blocks A-F have no logic correlation to each other, they all do several things. My aim is to make B and C start working, after A has finished. And D/E/F after B AND C have finished.
In this case, the word "parallel" was the wrong word, this does not have to be calculated really parallely. Just making sure, that this complies with a predifined steady order.

**Edit:**
My new idea is to use the matlab workspace als buffer, so my block A can push its results to workspace (by the "to workspace" block). But now I have to make sure, that block B and C may read the results (with "From workspace") of A AFTER A pushed its information to workspace...how to do this?

**Edit2:**
Here's a screenshot which should make some thinks clearer:
[image]

As the documentation of "Sorted order" refers, the set up seems to be ok (including the subsystems timing). But unfortunately problem still exists. The variable "simin" is loaded from workspace, before it was written :( As you see, the display shows "1", which it shouldn't do. In the very first run of the simulation I get an exception, that the variable "simin" does not exist.

It would be nice, if you can help me with my issue.

Greets, poeschlorn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in your example, if you have Block A connected with the same wire to both B and C, when Block A is finished, Block B and C will work in parallel.

EDIT:
I am using the same blocks as you are, but it works for me. I think you are over complicating things. The way you are setting block priorities is no different than how Simulink runs the blocks without them. Below you can see my setup and the output on both binary displays.

[image]

The error you see on the first run is due to Simulink not creating the variable until the first time step is being executed. When Simulink builds the simulation it sees that the variable used as input from the workspace is not created.

Comment: if I see that right, my solution of block A is used for calculating B and C!? Sorry for that stupid question, I simulink knowledge is very rudimentary

Comment: Block A will be run, then its ouptut will be B and C's input. So Block A's result can be used for calculations in B and C.

Comment: ok that makes sense. Is it now possible to store the result in workspace and then read it out for further calculation in the same step? At the beginning of my simulation it is not yet clear, which block gets which input. Therefor I have to use the workspace as "buffer"

Comment: "ToWorkspace" are only updated at the end of the simulation. You can use Goto/From labels (in "Signal Routing") to do that. It's not really a "storage", just a connection.

Comment: hi, I used the priotity functions of the blocks, and I read, that they are not compatible to the goto/from blocks as you can see here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/ug/f13-88939.html#f13-82250 is there any other possibility or workaround?

Comment: You don't have to assign priory everywhere, just when you want to force it. Labels priority are always well calculated.
It seems you think too much as in a classical (text) language. Let Simulink do its job, generally it works.

Comment: Hi akd, this is absolutlely right, this works very fine. My "evil problem" now are the from/to workspace blocks, so the "to" is executed before the "from" block, using the matlab workspace as buffer. I can't hardcode or hard-line my blocks, because they will be dynamically connected via variables, so I have to assign the vairables with values before and during the runtime. But you're absolutely right, hard-connecting the blocks work absolutely correct and very good :)

Comment: The to and from workspace blocks are intended to be used as input from the workspace and output to the workspace. In your example, they both use the same variable so the value read from the workspace will always be a time step behind, since the output isn't saved until the simulation completes.

Answer (score 1):

If the connection between the block are not enough to set the order, you can use [block priorities](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/ug/f13-91940.html#f13-91958).

A tip to test the execution order is to add an "embedded Matlab block" with a `disp` command displaying the name of the block.

Comment: Hi, I tried using this, but I get an error because the variable has not yet a name. Error evaluating parameter 'VariableName' in 'MySim/From Workspace': Undefined function or variable 'output1'.

Comment: Which part of my answer are you referring to ?

Comment: hey, I just added a screenshot, maybe this can help understanding my problem. The exception is thrown only when the variable isn't in workspace...but regarding to the order (as shown in the screenshot) it should exist, after the block "to workspace" has done its task.

Comment: As I wrote in another comment, you should use Goto/From block. They are equivalent to a wire (not a buffer). To/FromWorkspace are update respectively at beginning/end of simulation.

Comment: http://mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/ug/f13-88939.html#f13-82250 says that it is not possible to get this working with priority...is there a workaround?

Comment: Regarding your edit 2, the problem stay the same. The 'From workspace" is evaluate only at the beginning of the simulation (hence the problem the first time when the variable isn't defined) and the 'To workspace' at the end. During the second simulation, you send into the display results from the first simulation (and so on).

Comment: hi Clement J, I got a hint that the to/from workspace blocks only can be timed, when they are used in "Enabled Subsystems", I think I should try this. Maybe this enabled sybsystem is handled as own simulation in the main simulation

Comment: I tried this out, it seems you're right. "From/To workspace" seems to fail, even with enabled subsystems. Is there any other way to store about 160 signals in any other structure so my blocks can read or write them in a desired order? I need to set connection between the input and output ports of my blocks dynamically by a config m-file, which mustn't be the same every simulation...I am very clueless how to do so

Comment: You should try with a `Selector` (in Signal routing). Set the vector Element in your config m-file the way you want (but it can't change during simulation).
(if it works well, it would be good to accept my answer)

Comment: mh, if I can't modify it during simulation it is not really usable for my needs...I have got another idea but I also don't know how to implement this...when I say, every block I want to read in/do something/write out to the workspace shall be an own simulation, I can have several from/to workspace blocks, because every block is initalised on its own...but how can I start several simulations in a way that they act after each other and do not overlap? In this case the workspace could act as common data source/sink...any oppinion on this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you're asking.  When you say that Block A must be finished, do you mean the Output function?  The way simulation works in Simulink is that the blocks are run serially, so Block B and C would never run until Block A finished it's Output function.

I don't know of any obvious way of running blocks B and C in parallel currently in Simulink.

Comment: hi, I modified my question a little bit, so it hopefully might me clearer